# Struts2-Maven in eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, maven, struts2, maven-2, maven-3

I have imported this [Struts2-maven](http://code.google.com/p/struts2-examples/downloads/detail?name=Form_Tags_Struts_2_Mvn_2_3_1_2.zip&can=2&q=maven) project in to my Eclipse.

here is my `pom.xml` for Struts2

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>manning</groupId>
<artifactId>Form_Tags_Struts2_Mvn</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>Form_Tags_Struts2_Mvn</name>
<build>
    <finalName>Form_Tags_Struts2_Mvn</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
        <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.0_05</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_05/lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
        </dependencies>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
```

But when am try to run it shows an exception.
Here is my Exception:

> SEVERE: Exception starting filter struts2
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
>       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
>       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:532)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:514)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:133)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:256)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:382)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:103)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4650)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5306)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Can any one please help me? actually what  happens ?

Comment: Did you examine the WAR file that gets built to verify whether it had the struts core jar in the lib directory?

Comment: please post your whole 'pom.xml'

Comment: Did you read the readme?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try checking your deployment dependency of your project (Properties > Deployment Assembly) and check if Maven Dependencies are included. If you try to add them using Add > Java Build path entries and then select your maven thing.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Is there anything that would cause this to fall off?  I find I have to keep doing this every once in awhile.  Frustrating.